# Query to list nested results

Tags: sql, nested

I have 3 tables

t_role 
t_role_access_id 
t_access

t_role

```
**id   NAME**

90   Dep1
91   Tes1
92   Bes1
```

t_role_access_id

```
**role_id   acc_type acc_id**

90        role       91
91        access     103
91        access     105
92        access     102
```

t_access

```
**id     name application**

100    Read        App1
101    Modify      App2
102    Read        App1
103    Write       App2
104    Read        App3
105    Modify      App3
```

When i run the below query i get output something like below

```
select * from t_role_access_id trai
left join t_access ta on ta.id=trai.acc_id
left join t_role tr on tr.id=trai.ROLE_ID
where tr.id=90


**role_id,   acc_type, acc_id, id, name, application ,id ,  NAME**
    90        role       91                         90   Dep1
```

What i need is something like this. The query should check if acc_type is like "role" then go back again to "t_role_access_id" table and get granular access details

```
**role_id,   acc_type, acc_id, id, name, application ,id ,  NAME**
90        role       91                             90   Dep1
91        access     103   103    Write       App2  90   Dep1
91        access     105   105    Modify      App3  90   Dep1
```

This is just example. I have role nested with roles in different depth level.  So i need to write a query to get the granuall details. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be enough to do another join, something like this, where in tmp1 and tmp2 you can filter or group (or otherwise) as needed?

```
select tmp1.* , tmp2.* from
(
select 
tr.id as tr_id, tr.name as tr_name, 
trai.role_id, trai.acc_type, trai.acc_id,
ta.id, ta.name, ta.application
from t_role_access_id trai
left join t_access ta on ta.id=trai.acc_id
left join t_role tr on tr.id=trai.ROLE_ID
-- where tr.id=90
) as tmp1

left join
(
select trai2.role_id as det_role_id, trai2.acc_type as det_type, trai2.acc_id as det_acc_id
from t_role_access_id as trai2 
-- where acc_type = 'role'
) as tmp2

on tmp2.det_acc_id = tmp1.acc_id
```